# Column_to_rowname function in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation, tibble

I have a problem that is occuring:

Using the same dataset, imported in different ways, has differents results after using `column_to_rowname` function:

When I import the dataset from a `csv` format:

```
library(tibble)
  data <- read.table(text = data, sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  data <- as.data.frame(data)
    $ Contas.Resultado              <chr> "% C.M.V.", "% Despesas Financeiras", "% Despesas Operacionais", "% Despesas Pessoal", "% Despesa...
    $ `Foz do Iguaçu`               <dbl> 6.861259e-01, 4.351738e-03, 1.948886e-02, 5.030020e-02, NA, 5.405629e-03, 3.937407e-03, 1.582344e...
    $ `Galinha Caipira`             <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.556879e+06, 1.144605e+06, 3.651308e+05, 9.2...
    $ `Indústria de Aves`           <dbl> 6.996671e-01, 6.270924e-04, 1.519735e-01, 2.824831e-02, 5.424471e-03, 1.509008e-02, 1.940629e-02,...
    $ `Postos de Gasolina`          <dbl> 7.137772e-01, 1.390428e-03, 3.290988e-02, 4.004685e-02, 1.485064e-02, 3.844833e-03, 2.604383e-02,...
    $ `São Paulo`                   <dbl> 5.394683e-01, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.804614e-02, 2.331499e-03, NA, NA, 2.207766e+07, NA, NA, N...
    $ `Total das Áreas de Negócios` <dbl> 6.656677e-01, 3.846783e-02, 5.555819e-02, 4.171821e-02, 9.965640e-03, 1.030095e-02, 2.735231e-02,...
    $ `Unidade MS`                  <dbl> 6.230891e-01, 1.412913e-03, 3.335100e-02, 2.960971e-02, 1.512218e-02, 4.711866e-03, 2.085070e-02,...
    $ `Unidade RS`                  <dbl> 8.374991e-01, 1.359509e-03, 3.230330e-02, 5.439893e-02, 1.447725e-02, 2.652581e-03, 3.318487e-02,...
```

And pass the first column into row name, everything works well:

```
data <- data %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var = "Contas.Resultado")
```

My problem is:

The real dataset is an mdx api query (converted from `json` to dataframe, followed by `cbind` function), not a `csv`. When I import the data, I tried to create a very similar format:

```
Data1 <- as.data.frame(Data1)
    $ `Contas Resultado`            <fct> % C.M.V., % Despesas Financeiras, % Despesas Operacionais, % Despesas Pesso...
    $ `Foz do Iguaçu`               <dbl> 6.861259e-01, 4.351738e-03, 1.948886e-02, 5.030020e-02, NA, 5.405629e-03, 3...
    $ `Galinha Caipira`             <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.556879e+06, 1.144605e...
    $ `Indústria de Aves`           <dbl> 6.996671e-01, 6.270924e-04, 1.519735e-01, 2.824831e-02, 5.424471e-03, 1.509...
    $ `Postos de Gasolina`          <dbl> 7.137772e-01, 1.390428e-03, 3.290988e-02, 4.004685e-02, 1.485064e-02, 3.844...
    $ `São Paulo`                   <dbl> 5.394683e-01, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.804614e-02, 2.331499e-03, NA, NA, 2...
    $ `Total das Áreas de Negócios` <dbl> 6.656677e-01, 3.846783e-02, 5.555819e-02, 4.171821e-02, 9.965640e-03, 1.030...
    $ `Unidade MS`                  <dbl> 6.230891e-01, 1.412913e-03, 3.335100e-02, 2.960971e-02, 1.512218e-02, 4.711...
    $ `Unidade RS`                  <dbl> 8.374991e-01, 1.359509e-03, 3.230330e-02, 5.439893e-02, 1.447725e-02, 2.652...
```

When I try to do the same proccess:

```
Data1 <- Data1 %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="`Contas Resultado`")
```

I get an error message:

> ```
> Error: Column `num2` not found
> ```

`Dput` of `Data1`

```
structure(list(`Contas Resultado` = structure(1:32, .Label = c("% C.M.V.", 
    "% Despesas Financeiras", "% Despesas Operacionais", "% Despesas Pessoal", 
    "% Despesas Pró-labore", "% Despesas Tributárias", "% Despesas Vendas", 
    "% Devoluções", "% Impostos", "% Receitas Financeiras", "% Receitas Operacionais", 
    "C.M.V.", "Despesas Financeiras", "Despesas Operacionais", "Despesas Pessoal", 
    "Despesas Pró-labore", "Despesas Tributárias", "Despesas Vendas", 
    "Devoluções", "EBTI", "EBTIDA R$", "Faturamento", "Impostos", 
    "Margem Bruta", "Margem Ebtida", "Margem Líquida", "Receita Líquida", 
    "Receitas Financeiras", "Receitas Operacionais", "Resultado Bruto", 
    "Resultado Líquido", "ROE"), class = "factor"), `Foz do Iguaçu` = c(0.68612585544488, 
    0.0043517384317626, 0.0194888625807808, 0.0503002002622742, NA, 
    0.00540562915716222, 0.00393740650270395, 0.0158234413058695, 
    0.00298555558943327, 0.00309379115135203, 0.00519697211916096, 
    11890516.6296312, 76861.0238892454, 344215.06620491, 888409.30001084, 
    NA, 95474.9919601125, 69543.03435545, 279475.873674674, 4133565.86239994, 
    4133565.86239994, 17662142.4045733, 52731.3079773401, 0.31387414455512, 
    0.238521714549327, 0.237239652976778, 17329935.2229212, 54642.9798851882, 
    91789.6616412177, 5439418.59329004, 4111347.81839589, 0.00292941908441637
    ), `Galinha Caipira` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 9556878.92418847, 1144604.93814171, 365130.776145752, 
    925127.444386077, 1135558.62804292, NA, -12452272.7712085, -12452272.7712085, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 231098.009820487, 675027.93969646, NA, 
    -12221174.761388, -0.00870783600935179), `Indústria de Aves` = c(0.699667052082928, 
    0.000627092426749223, 0.151973469590285, 0.0282483062516762, 
    0.0054244708112611, 0.0150900776642944, 0.0194062924371954, 0.016149713612494, 
    0.0441365437855457, 0.00474956854966594, 0.0219427540766736, 
    44256601.893048, 42210.7063455348, 10229604.478628, 1901443.72517686, 
    365130.776145752, 1015739.96088709, 1306272.05238058, 1087065.94081398, 
    5656015.9308692, 5659151.43204849, 67311778.2084378, 2970909.24617965, 
    0.300332947917072, 0.0894673705252147, 0.093804749215047, 63253803.0214441, 
    319701.904800885, 1477005.79569135, 18997201.1283961, 5933507.12932455, 
    0.0042277447177762), `Postos de Gasolina` = c(0.713777232261634, 
    0.00139042807966732, 0.0329098763968368, 0.0400468547401319, 
    0.0148506386870228, 0.00384483346282912, 0.0260438268929179, 
    0.0157740600011077, 0.00456634697984958, 0.00816671484651574, 
    0.00123371381293295, 58692862.9049296, 116706.739805739, 2762317.90615421, 
    3361366.1321577, 1246500.73638479, 322719.301418422, 2186010.31810629, 
    1324008.8740655, 13760319.9963958, 14644840.3358183, 83935833.5122681, 
    383280.139859902, 0.286222767738367, 0.178099228499824, 0.1742593567928, 
    82228544.4983427, 685480.017699313, 103552.797204126, 23535681.5934131, 
    14329093.2742893, 0.0102097708961202), `São Paulo` = c(0.539468287243312, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.018046138403897, 0.00233149930616966, 
    NA, NA, 22077662.0410456, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 753898.283945763, 
    18847194.0869442, 18847194.0869442, 41776155.4894737, 97401.0775381438, 
    0.460531712756688, 0.460531712756689, 0.460531712756689, 40924856.1279898, 
    NA, NA, 18847194.0869442, 18847194.0869442, 0.0134290097760533
    ), `Total das Áreas de Negócios` = c(0.665667747374264, 0.0384678251694839, 
    0.0555581900068015, 0.0417182114705366, 0.00996563959620955, 
    0.0103009450485867, 0.0273523085436607, 0.0159912681090607, 0.018972970689887, 
    0.0323679824248229, 0.0303066463387605, 177825304.573185, 10648545.0440942, 
    15379447.2718227, 11548306.9824147, 2758657.70071218, 2851475.92470683, 
    7571581.92083575, 4426653.65201372, 57592849.407689, 58533637.2998705, 
    276816924.200374, 5252039.38931835, 0.334332252625736, 0.219113666531027, 
    0.209271093315442, 267138231.159041, 8960005.33741123, 8389392.62232419, 
    89312926.5858569, 55904309.7010059, 0.0398329596456148), `Unidade MS` = c(0.623089149597576, 
    0.00141291279236638, 0.0333509956937994, 0.0296097093525557, 
    0.0151221778944891, 0.00471186576819375, 0.0208507035043875, 
    0.0157192326945189, 0.00788709493679481, 0.0129396633998504, 
    NA, 29564762.3727304, 68661.7083993295, 1620720.22670253, 1438909.20963995, 
    734875.19864209, 228977.156368338, 1013257.81157475, 763889.588489469, 
    12847185.5706182, 12847185.5706182, 48595857.2746256, 383280.139859902, 
    0.376910850402424, 0.270759555953755, 0.282564989493201, 47448687.5462762, 
    628814.035760828, NA, 17883925.1735459, 13407337.8979797, 0.00955300141083288
    ), `Unidade RS` = c(0.837499147059275, 0.00135950944288507, 0.0323032950496358, 
    0.054398930819598, 0.0144772462296604, 0.00265258087384434, 0.0331848696967253, 
    0.0158494528069155, NA, 0.00160345274590558, 0.00293018864833944, 
    29128100.5321992, 48045.0314064091, 1141597.67945168, 1922456.92251775, 
    511625.537742699, 93742.145050084, 1172752.50653153, 560119.28557603, 
    913134.425777582, 1797654.76520007, 35339976.2376425, NA, 0.162500852940725, 
    0.051686663567294, 0.0265025637563726, 34779856.9520664, 56665.9819384857, 
    103552.797204126, 5651756.4198672, 921755.376309658, 0.000656769485287294
    )), .Names = c("Contas Resultado", "Foz do Iguaçu", "Galinha Caipira", 
    "Indústria de Aves", "Postos de Gasolina", "São Paulo", "Total das Áreas de Negócios", 
    "Unidade MS", "Unidade RS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -32L))
```

Comment: Please provide some data using `dput` and a [mcve].

Comment: `> remove_rownames
Error: object 'remove_rownames' not found
> column_to_rownames
Error: object 'column_to_rownames' not found
> `

Comment: please note: not every function that is stupid should be used. Stick to `base` where you can. Use stuff like `rownames(df)<-NULL` to remove rownames etc...

Comment: You should you library(tibble)

Comment: rownames(df)<-NULL
df <- column_to_rownames(df, var="`Contas Resultado`")
Same error occured : Error: Column `num2` not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution of your problem with base R function looks like that:

```
rownames(Data1) <- Data1[, 1]
Data1 <- Data1[, -1]
```